# Верстка. Ресурсы для обучения/практики

Tags: вёрстка

Начал-таки изучать HTML и CSS. Какие посоветуйте ресурсы для прокачивания скилла "верстка"?

Comment: Ну, отсюда я изучил теги а атрибуты пока по HTML, но по верстке желательно найти последовательную практику и теорию.

Comment: https://webref.ru/practice

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать [вот этот](http://htmlbook.ru/practical) ресурс для практики.

Comment: Я видел, что многие используют Adobe Photoshop, вот что нужно сделат, чтобы достичь их уровня?

Comment: @Alexandrietz Фотошоп - это инструмент рисования и дизайна, а не вёрстки. Вёрстка - это процесс "превращения" нарисованного - в html/css/js код. Если Вы действительно имели ввиду дизайн - таком случае Ваш вопрос в корне задан неверно. Вам нужно разобраться в терминах. В ютубе есть очень много видео по дизайну для начинающих, наример ([Вот это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhYY-qAoZtw)). Поищите.

Comment: Нет, имел в виду верстку. Просто, видимо, не отделил мух от котлет.

Comment: @Alexandrietz Если мой ответ был полезен, пожалуйста не забудьте указать что это правильный ответ. Спасибо.